# CORS issue with GeoServer 2.2X version with Tomcat

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, cors

We are using GeoServer 2.2x in our environment, we are directly using GeoServer WAR in Docker file. Only additional configuration added in web.xml  with CORS filter enabled and env variables to set data directory. Below is the CORS configuration in Apache Tomcat web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
  <param-value>*</param-value>
</init-param>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

GeoServer is deployed properly and working fine, but we are getting CORS issue while trying to retrieve layers from another application. For options method, CORS is the error and POST methods, 403.

[image: CORS Error in Browser]
[image: Request Header]
[image: ResponseHeader]

Has anybody faced same issue?

Comment: 2.2x is very old we're up to 2.23.x now

Comment: @IanTurton Thanks . I just upgraded to 2.23x . But CORS issue is till there

Comment: if you are using Apache as well as tomcat then you need to fix CORS there not in tomcat

Comment: I am only using Tomcat . This is my Docker file

FROM <NexusRepo>/tomcat:9.0

ADD geoserver.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/geoserver.war
ADD web.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/web.xml
ADD setenv.sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

Comment: please [edit] your question with new information, and also add the exact error message